# Redirect to root in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

In old site i have all my product categories in a category called `/webshop/`.

I want to strip out the /webshop/ in URL and redirect to root with a 301, because i have removed the "webshop" category.

**Example.**

Old site:

```
www.site.com/webshop/shoes.html
```

New site:

```
www.site.com/shoes.html
```

It needs to be generic so it works for all my categories. Only categories needs to be redirected like this, because my products dont have category path in URL.

This is a Magento webshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /webshop/(.*) /$1
```

Add that to your .htaccess file and report back.